# How do you translate "share" in the context of social media

Tags: translation

I'm creating a website in Chinese and realize I dont have translations for small UI terms, such as:
- About
- Latest recipe 
- Read More 
- Share (In the context of Social Media) 
- Nutritional value
- Search

I feel as though these terms would require another level of understanding of their context, and cant be simply translated word for word. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you have Facebook, a good way is to switch the language to Chinese, and compare the terms on the buttons/links.

Comment: about: 关于; Latest recipe: 最新菜谱(I don't know the context of recipe, I translated it as a usage in restaurant),  read more: 更多 or 阅读全文; share: 分享 or 转发, NV: 营养表; search: 搜索

Answer (score 1):

About - 關於

Latest recipe - 最新食譜

Read More - 更多

Share (In the context of Social Media) - 分享

Nutritional value - 營養價值

Search - 搜索